# What this symbol .*? means in PHP (HTML Parsing)

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, screen-scraping, symbols

i just wanna ask what this symbol .*? means in php.
here is the sample code:

```
    function parse($html) {
    //echo "Find table(id=weekdays)..\n";
    $pattern = "/(<table.*?id=\"weekdays\".*)/ims";
    //$pattern = "/(<div.*?id=\"flexBox_flex_calendar_mainCal\".*)/ims";
    //echo $pattern."\n";
    $match = array();
    //$html = str_replace("\r", "", $html);
    //$html = str_replace("\n", "", $html);
    if (preg_match($pattern, $html, $match) > 0) {
        //print_r($match);
        //echo $match[1];
        //echo count($match);
        $this->parseTable($match[1]);
    } else {
        echo "Error: no match calendar data(table id=weekdays) found, maybe fx.com change its site html'!\n";
    }
}
```

I am maintaining a website that has the function to extract the table values from another/an external website then parse it to insert on our database..

I have to change the value of $pattern but i cant since i didn't know what does that symbols mean..

Thank you so much for the help..

Comment: http://php.net/regexp.reference.dot; http://php.net/regexp.reference.repetition - what have you tried so far to find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a wildcard character in a regular expression.

`(<table.*?id=\"weekdays\".*)`

`/./s`  means ANY character

`*` means 0 or more times

So `/.*/s` means  "match any character 0 or more times"

STRING : `hello , now this is some garbage , world.  And this is a long sentence which ends in world`

`hello.*world` will match this WHOLE string.

See example : http://regexr.com?334em

And `/.*?/s` means "match any character 0 or more times, but the non greedy match i.e. The earliest match is returned (here: a zero-length string).

`/hello.*?world/s` will match only `hello , now this is some garbage , world` as it is the smallest non-greedy match.

See same example with difference : 
http://regexr.com?334ep

`ims` are flags `i` , `m` and `s`

You can read about them here: [PHP: Possible modifiers in regex patterns<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers)

Answer (score 4):

That is called a regular expression, you can learn more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

`/.*?/ims` means "match any character, if any ( non-greedy )".

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

these  may be helpful for you